# What is the currently accepted way to retrieve data from a SQL Server using C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Let's say I have a form in C# containing textboxes that correspond to fields in a SQL Server database table, and I want to extract data from the table and populate the textboxes.

From VS2005, I am familiar with the following code pattern:

```
command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID = " + CustId;
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
FormCustomer.textBoxName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
FormCustomer.textBoxAddress = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Address"));
FormCustomer.textBoxSuburb = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Suburb"));
```

What is the currently accepted way to do this in C# 4.0 using VS2010?

Comment: I tell you what *isn't* usually generally accepted... having your UI code (`FormCustomer.textBoxName`) and your DAL code (commands, readers, etc) **that** close together...

Comment: @MarcGravell: I agree, I was just doing this for the sake of simplicity. I would normally have a business object to accept the SQL data.

Comment: It is hugely subjective, and would depend perhaps on what other requirements you have for the data / system. There is no "one answer" here. We use dapper, but any of the tools Jon lists will do something similar (with different performance / features etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the way you've got it is certainly one option, although you should be using parameterized SQL instead of creating SQL on the fly. (I hope you've also got appropriate `using` statements to close connections etc).

Other options:

- Reading into a `DataTable` instead (still basic ADO.NET)
- [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)
- [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)
- [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive#readme)
- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)
- [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)
- [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/)
- [Simple.Data](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data#readme)

That's just off the top of my head. There are bound to be more.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SimpleData](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data) project:

> Prompted by the need for an easy-to-use database access component
>   which prevents SQL injection attacks while not requiring lots of
>   boilerplate ADO.NET code or a pre-generated ORM model. Inspired by
>   Ruby's ActiveRecord and DataMapper gems.

With SimpleData your code will be look like:

```
var customer = db.Customer.FindById(CustId);

FormCustomer.textBoxName = customer.Name;
FormCustomer.textBoxAddress = customer.Address;
FormCustomer.textBoxSuburb = customer.Suburb;
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx

Entity Framework:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Long story short, the latter is the main ORM tool from Ms. Linq to SQL is a nice way to start with small and simple things.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single "currently accepted" way; I'm lazy, so I use dapper; so my approach would be:

```
var cust = conn.Query(
    "select Name, Address, Suburb from Customer where Id = @CustId",
    new {CustId}).Single();
FormCustomer.textBoxName = cust.Name;
FormCustomer.textBoxAddress = cust.Address;
FormCustomer.textBoxSuburb = cust.Suburb;
```

There is also `Query<T>` etc for filling typed objects, but in the above the `dynamic` usage (as shown) is probably fine. The `new {CustId}` specifies the parameters - fully named, typed, and SQL-injection safe (note the `CustId` in the anonymous type matches to `@CustId` in the TSQL). No messing with commands and readers, brutally fast.

Comment: Just have to add, dapper rocks!

Comment: Where do statements like "using" fit into the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what you have to do. Your code is still valid of course and there is no definitive pattern, but it is connection oriented. The other approach is a "connection-less" approach using DataSet, SqlDataAdapter, etc. Have a look here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson05.

**Edit**: Ok here is a version with SqlDataAdapter:

```
DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter daCustomers = 
         new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID = " + CustId, conn);
SqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(daCustomers);
daCustomers.Fill(dsCustomers, tableName);
```

Comment: No offence but that seems like more code than what I had. Why would you do it your way?

Comment: Because it does not serve the same purpose. The SqlDataAdapter model is used when you want to read data from the database, then perform a number of modifications on the DataSet (in memory) and then only update the actual database when you need to. Between the first and last step you save a lot of trips to the database. Check the link I posted, it explains everything better.